# Save figure using `iplot` in R

Tags: r

How can I save this plot:

```
# Model

mod_twfe = feols(y ~ i(time_to_treat, treat, ref = -1) + ## Our key interaction: time × treatment status
                 factor(id) + factor(time),                             ## FEs
                 cluster = ~factor(id),                          ## Clustered SEs
                 data = df)

# Plot

plot = iplot(mod_twfe,
              xlab = 'Time to treatment',
              main = 'Event study: Staggered treatment (TWFE)')
```

I was trying with `ggsave`,

```
ggsave("plot.pdf", plot = plot, device='pdf')
```

but it raises the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("grid.draw") : 
  no applicable method for 'grid.draw' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: Hi! You need to save the plot in the object `plot ` or run `ggsave ` without `plot = plot`.

Comment: Does not look to me that an object named "plot" has been created. In R running a plot routine does not typically create an object in the workspace. There are three main plotting paradigms: base, trellis, and ggplot. If you are in either of the the latter two you need to assign the output of your plotting function to an object name. If you are in the first paradigm, then it's an ink on paper model so there is no object created. And as always: specify which package you are using. If I'm correct in my memory, `fixest::iplot` is a base plot paradigm and the suggestion to save an object will fail.

Comment: Sorry, it was with `plot = iplot(...)`; the error is the same. I'm using `fixest::iplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iplot()` doesn't output an object with the class `ggplot` which is why `ggsave()` doesn't work here, and assigning it to a variable doesn't work. Instead you can use the `pdf` function to save to pdf:

```r
pdf("plot.pdf")
iplot(est_did)
dev.off()
```

As a sidenote, I'd recommend not saving objects as a variable called `plot` as plot is the name of a function (and it could easily cause issues further down the line).